# Пропадает регион карты при рендере в RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Хочу создать картограмму демографического показателя:

- загружаю карту с *GADM*
- подключаю
- добавляю данные с *CSV*

При рендере карты по субъектам все прорисовывается. При рендере показателей пропадают регионы, хотя на эти регионы точно есть данные.

```
rusmap <-readRDS("RUS_adm1.rds")
rusmap@data <- merge(rusmap@data, mortality, by.x=c("NAME_1"), by.y=c("X"))
spplot(rusmap, "X2014",
col.regions = plotcol,  col = "transparent",
at = brks.eq$brks, # задает границы классов
par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = NA)))
```

Ошибок никаких не выдает.

Comment: Предположение вслепую: что-то не так с данными. Что-то, что не дает их корректно отобразить. Попробуйте сравнить данные для нормально отображаемых регионов и для тех, которые не рендерятся.